# Can I use n2 or n2d machine types with Cloud Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I want to use [Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) with n2 and other [machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) that are not n1s. When I look at the [Dataproc pricing](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/pricing) and the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) it looks like I can only use n1 machine types.

Is there any way to use n2 and other machine types, like n2d? These machine types may save me money or be more appropriate for my workloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Dataproc **does** support machine types other than n1 machine types when using the [`gcloud`](http://cloud.google.com/sdk) command line tool. If you specify a n2 (or other machine type) it should use that machine type appropriately. For example:

```
--master-machine-type=n2-standard-4 --worker-machine-type=n2-standard-4
```

Keep in mind, the machine type you want to use must be available in the zone and region you specify. Support for machine types other than n1 is coming soon in the Cloud Console.

*Disclaimer* - I am a PM for Dataproc and this is a common question as of Feb 2020.